# How do I use swagger api to generate swagger with additionalProperties as false for object

Tags: swagger

I somehow have to generate a swagger doc with addtionalProperties as false to not allow additional properties. For example, this is what I want to get:

```
"TestDTO" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "additionalProperties":false
      "properties" : {
        "property1" : {
          "description" : "This is a test object.",
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/TestDTO"
        },
        "perperty2" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "this is a property."
        }
      }
    },
```

I looked at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-models/src/main/java/io/swagger/models/ModelImpl.java

but setAdditionalProperties accept a Property only, how do I set it with a boolean value?

```
public void setAdditionalProperties(Property additionalProperties) {
type(OBJECT);
this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

addtionalProperties as boolean value is not supported in swagger spec 2.0,
swagger spec 3.0 added support for boolean value.

see details here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/1J5KznDibzA